# TableView and cells not visible on UIControllerView Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, firebase

---

Im learning how to code in Swift 4 but i have ran into an issue with my table view not showing on the View controller! Im attempting to load a progress view in each cell (the count of the progress doesnt matter for not, i just want it to work before i go more complex). The UiViewController has a tab bar controller also.

i will later be looking to set the countdown speed of the progress view to values stored in firebase.

I dont understand why this is blank! there seems to be no errors??

### FirstViewController

import UIKit
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
var arrayOfProcesses :[processCell] = []


@IBOutlet weak var tabelView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var lblDisplayName: UILabel!




@IBAction func btnLogOut(_ sender: Any) {


    try! Auth.auth().signOut()
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}

func CreateArray() -> [processCell]{

    var tempProcesses :[processCell] = []

    let process1 = processCell(process:"Position passenger Bridge/Open Door",progress: 10,timeleft: "10")
     let process2 = processCell(process:"Deplane Passengers",progress: 10,timeleft: "10")
     let process3 = processCell(process:"Service Cabin",progress: 10,timeleft: "10")
     let process4 = processCell(process:"Unload Baggage compartment",progress: 10,timeleft: "10")
     let process5 = processCell(process:"Position passenger Bridge/Open Door",progress: 10,timeleft: "10")

    tempProcesses.append(process1)
    tempProcesses.append(process2)
    tempProcesses.append(process3)
    tempProcesses.append(process4)
    tempProcesses.append(process5)

    return tempProcesses

}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    arrayOfProcesses = CreateArray()


    tabelView.delegate = self
     tabelView.dataSource = self



//    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.30, target: self, selector: #selector(SetProgressbar), userInfo: nil, repeats: /true)

    self.tabelView.reloadData()
}





func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayOfProcesses.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let process = arrayOfProcesses[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "processCell") as! ProcessTableViewCell

    cell.setProcess(process: process)

    return cell
}
```

}

### ProcessTableViewCell.swift

import UIKit

class ProcessTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var progressViewBar: UIProgressView!
@IBOutlet weak var lblProcess: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblTimer: UILabel!

var progressValue: Float = 0


func setProcess(process : processCell) {

    lblProcess.text = process.process
    lblTimer.text = process.timeleft


   Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.30, target: self, selector: #selector(setProgressbar), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

@objc func setProgressbar(){

```
    progressValue += 0.30
    progressViewBar.progress = progressValue

}
```

}

### ProcessCell

import Foundation
import UIKit

class processCell{

var process : String
    var progress : Int
    var timeleft : String

```
init(process : String,progress : Int,timeleft : String){

    self.process = process
    self.progress = progress
    self.timeleft = timeleft
}
```

}

Any Help is much appreciated :) thanks

Comment: Make sure the IBOutlet for the tableView is connected from the storyboard or nib, and make sure the view controller is initialized from the storyboard or the nib.  Also make sure that if the tableView has autolayout constraints, it has no conflicts.  This can sometimes cause things to disappear or show incorrectly.

Comment: Though invoking tableView would cause crashing if the IBOutlet weren't connected ... Is the correct classname being used in the storyboard for the view controller (ie FirstViewController.swift) ?

Comment: There was a conflict in the Constraints thanks a lot !! ,

Comment: but the progress bar does not move, am i using it incorrectly ??

Comment: I’ve spend all day trying to fix this !! Really appreciate it thanks again 

Comment: Spoke too soon regarding the setProcess, sorry.  I thought is was intended to be a setter.

Comment: Or did that help?  Now I regret deleting it if it was helping out.

Comment: I have actually noticed that the bar does load but completes in a second rather than 30 (what I wanted for example purposes

Comment: it’s ok ill attempt it tomorrow, but any material you have on setting the progress view completion time from firebase would be great 

Comment: Not too much experience with firebase but I'll circle back and check out your code again later to see what might be going on.  But note the timer fires every .3 seconds and the progress goes up by .3 for every fire, so it would reach 1.0 in just about a second.